# How do I parse the userInfo dictionary in application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm new to Swift so excuse me if this is a dumb question. This is the JSON that I'm pushing to my application:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Jack Terrance needs your help",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "default",
    "data": {
      "from": "Jack Terrance",
      "from_num": "+1234567890"
    }
  }
}
```

I manage to recevie the JSON, but I can't figure out how to parse it:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        let message : String = userInfo.map({$0["aps"]!["alert"] as String})

        UIAlertView(title: "Notification", message: message!, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show();

    }
```

What I'm looking for is something equivalent to `valueForKeyPath` in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

//Please Try Below. Hope this will work for you.

```
if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {

    if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSString {
       //Do stuff
    }else if let badge = alert["badge"] as? NSString {
       //Do stuff
    }else if let sound = aps["sound"] as? NSString {
       //Do stuff
    }

    if let data = aps["data"] as? NSDictionary {

        if let alert = data["from"] as? NSString {
            //Do stuff
        }else if let from_num = data["from_num"] as? NSString {
           //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```